# Proper way to handle an exception in a file with the caller in another

Tags: python

In file utility I have:

```
def validation():
        try:
            csrf_key, session_token, form_token = csrfKey, str( session[ 'csrf_token' ] ), request.values.get( 'csrf_token' )
        except:
            print( "except" )
            # Should I raise() here ?
        else:
            print( "after except" )
```

In file controller I have at some point:

```
def validation() # call
```

Ideally I wanted the exception in the utility file to completely interrupt execution of the script but without exiting.
But since it is not possible, would the proper way to handle this, be to re-raise() in the except from utility file, and re try/except in the controller file, so the exception would be propagated from utility to controller file. Is this the correct way to handle this situation ?

Comment: It's one ok way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to return "false" from the utility file if validation fails and have the controller print a message. You can also log the  cause of failure in the except clause. But ultimately, the "correct" way is up to you, depending on what you expect from the program.  Also, "not possible" is not true - everything's possible. There is "finally" clause in the try-except syntax that will execute no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the try/except block from the `validation` function and instead place it in the calling function in the controller file.

So:

```
def validation():
    csrf_key, session_token, form_token = csrfKey, str( session[ 'csrf_token' ] ), request.values.get( 'csrf_token' )
    return csrf_key, session_token, form_token
```

And call with:

```
try:
    csrf_key, session_token, form_token = validation()
except:
    print "Your err msg"
finally:
    # run other code...
```

If you want to keep re-trying, you can place it in a loop with a break clause on success. Hope this helps!